# Accessing DOM object model JavascriptCore

Tags: objective-c, dom, javascriptcore

I have a code where I need to access DOM object model in my Objective-C code. I am trying to execute a function that is suppose to return the content

```
    NSString *functionScr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"var fPreset=\"%@\";"
"var addFavorite = function() {"
"   if (fPreset != '') {"
"        var ft = window.document.createElement('div');"
"        ft.innerHTML =  decodeURIComponent(fPreset);"
"        var f = ft.innerHTML;"
"        var bub = encodeURIComponent(f.childNodes[1]);"
"        return bub;"
"       }"
"   }",encodedHTML];

[context evaluateScript:functionScr];
JSValue *retVAL = [context evaluateScript:@"addFavorite();"];
```

when this executes I get an error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window

How can I access window object in JavascriptCore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's is not possible :(
The DOM and any other window property is not available in the JavascriptCore.
It is a pure JS engine

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
JSContext *context = [yourwebview valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
[context evaluateScript:yourfunctionScr];
JSValue *retVAL = [context evaluateScript:@"addFavorite();"];
```

Comment: This does work if `yourwebview` is a `UIWebView`. Please be aware that using key-value coding this way is fragile since the internals of `UIWebView` could change at any time.